# Release Connection When Query Is Complete

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a question, Before I change my code, I got error `[error: connection lost: the server closed the connection.]`, possibly because its idle for sometime.
This is my old code.

```
const dbConn = mysql.createConnection({
    host        : 'localhost',
    user        : 'root',
    password    : '',
    database    : 'test'
});

dbConn.connect(function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Database Connected!");
})
    
module.exports = dbConn;
```

After searching for a while, most of it recommend using `createPool` intead of `createConnection`, so I change my code to this

```
const dbConn = mysql.createPool({
    host        : 'localhost',
    user        : 'root',
    password    : '',
    database    : 'test'
}); 

module.exports = dbConn;
```

Then my question is, do I have to release the connection everytime we complete a query? This is how I do query.

```
dbConn.query("SELECT * FROM spesialisasi s ORDER BY s.nama_spesialisasi ASC ", 
        function(err, res) {
            if(err) {
                console.log("error: ", err);
                result(err, null);
            } else {
                result(null, res);
            }
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my knowledge, `pool.query()` will automatically release the connection when the query completes. Here's the section on connection pooling from the [MySQL NPM docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections)

Comment: I see, thx for your answer.